# giving font size rem . doesn't get scaled on other screen sizes

Tags: css

I have used rem units for padding, margin and font size on larege screen the output is fine...but on small screen device the sizes are not reducing instead the larege screen measures presists, why dont rem units reduces relatively?

Comment: Because 1rem is supposed to be a font size that is readable on all screens. I.E. not that different between screens. Maybe you were looking for vw or vh instead.

Answer (score 0):

`rem` is `Relative Elastic Measurement` and is based on the font size of the `body` element. If the font size on `body` is 16px, then 1rem is 16px, no matter what element you have applied this to or the font size of the element.

If you're looking for a measurement that gets larger on large screens and smaller on small screens, may I suggest `vw`. This is `Viewport Width` and is the width of the screen as a percentage, e.g. `100vw` is the full width of the screen; `50vw` is 50% the full width of the screen.

You could then set your padding as `5vw` so you had more padding on large screen and less padding on small screen:

#### ScreenSize 1200px:

```
padding: 5vw; /* padding: 60px */
```

#### ScreenSize 360px:

```
padding: 5vw; /* padding: 18px */
```

Even though we haven't changed the value of padding (5vw), the amount of padding has changed (60px and 18px) relative to the screen size.